# Change paragraph text with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am currently setting up a Wordpress based website for one of my clients. Long story short:

I need to change some texts with javascript, like I've done many times. However, this time it's just not working.. this is the code I'm using through the element inspect console on the website:

```
target = document.querySelector('sc_services_item_content p')
target.innerHTML = "Paragraph text changed!"
```

The website is http://sifaclinic.nl/wordpress/tr_TR/therapieen/, if anyone is able to succesfully change the text, you'd be a true savior! Below the paragraph that needs to get changed.

[image: Paragraph that needs to be changed]

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It's still not working on the web page itself, only the 'target' variable's value changed to "Paragraph text changed!" in the console.

Comment: In WordPress simple running of JavaScript is blocked for security reasons. Follow here for alternative options: `https://www.godaddy.com/garage/industry/tech-svcs/wordpress/3-ways-to-insert-javascript-into-wordpress-pages-or-posts/`. Read also `https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Javascript`

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but it's not. I can change every text on the website with javascript, except for that specific paragraph..

Comment: Page that you have linked breaks on this code `document.getElementsByClassName("sc_title sc_title_regular")[0].innerHTML = 'Şifa kliniğine hoşgeldiniz';`, this element does not exist.

Comment: Excuse me, it needs to be "sc_services_item_content p", gonna update the post too.

Comment: Read https://ithemes.com/2015/02/17/adding-scripts-wordpress-right-way/

Answer (score 0):

`document.querySelector` returns the first element that matches the specified CSS selector, but it seems that you are looking for the third index, or index 2.

Your best bet is to use `document.querySelectorAll(.sc_services_item_description p)[2]`, which returns an array of elements that contains `.sc_services_item_description` and `p` and accesses index 2. Let me know how that works out.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I just wanted to try it on one, just to try and make it work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match more than one element on your page, use `querySelectorAll` instead of `querySelector`.

`querySelector` matches only the first found element.

`querySelectorAll` returns an array-line object, whom you can iterate on and choose element with specified `index` - in your particular case - I assume it's `2` - and change it's, e.g. `innerHTML` attribute.

```js
var target = document.querySelectorAll('.sc_services_item_description p')
target[2].innerHTML = 'Changed!';
```

```html
<div class="sc_services_item_description">
  <p>First element</p>
  <p>Second element</p>
  <p>Third element</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment! It does work, just like my code did. But for some reason it's not working on the web page itself..

Comment: @Acework It has to be something with your script then. Where are you placing it?

Comment: @Acework Try going into Developer Tools in your browser and call the function from there. (Cmd+Alt+I on Chrome Mac) Does it change the innerHTML of the element?

Comment: @AnthonyKrivonos the value of "target" variable indeed changes. But only in the console, not on the web page itself. You can see it for yourself, added the website in the post.

Comment: @Kinduser the value of "target" variable indeed changes. But only in the console, not on the web page itself. You can see it for yourself, added the website in the post.

Comment: @Acework You need to fix the javascript error first... all code after error will not run.

Comment: Open the page that you have linked in your question. The error is shown in developer console, you are trying to set innerHTML to an element that doesn't exist.